# Error: Could not find or load main class com.sparkarma.spark.WordCount

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

[package explore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ0QC.png) I tried to run the programme below. I am new to spark programming.i am getting following error in Scala IDE.I checked main class, no version problems in scala and spark. I mentioned output folder default. Please let me know what's wrong in my code.

```
package com.sparkarma.spark
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
object WordCount{

 def main(args:Array[String])  {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Word Count").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)



 val bigFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/home/chaitanya/files/bigText")

 val words = bigFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).count()

println(words)
}
}
```

[ScreenShot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2NjW.png)

Here is My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sparkarma.samp</groupId>
<artifactId>SparkMaro</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <version>2.10.6</version>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- mixed scala/java compile -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- for fatjar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                                    <artifactId> maven-scala-plugin                                     </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange> [2.15.2,)                                        </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Looking at the package explorer screenshot, your src/main/scala/ folder doesn't seem to be in the build path.

Answer (score 1):

Your project folder don't have Scala library container. Seems you are missing Scala libraries or Scala Nature in your project. Review your `pom.xml` and add appropriate Scala library in your project. Check if below dependency is added.

```
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

If yes then follow below steps:

1. `Right Click on project pom.xml ->Run As ->Maven Install`
2. `Right Click on Project ->Configure ->Add Scala Nature`
3. `Right Click on Project -> Scala -> Add scala library to build Path`
4. `Right Click on Scala Library container -> Properties -> Classpath container -> Select containers as per the version defined in pom.xml`

Your code looks good. If you still see the issue please provide your `pom.xml`

Please upgrade your spark-core_2.10 version from 1.4.0 to 1.6.2. Use below maven dependency and follow the above steps.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i modified changes,but still issue is coming.I posted pom.xml.Can you please review it..thanks

Comment: Please upgrade the Spark-core version. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Everything looks good in your code and pom except the suggested things. are you able to see Scala library container in your project ?? If not then you might be missing some steps. I suggests please review it again carefully.

Comment: instead of simple object,i created scala class with companion object.Then it got worked....thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the main method. Make sure that you don't do it

```
object WordCount{

  def main(args:Array[String])  {
     val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Word Count").setMaster("local[2]")
     val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

     val bigFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/home/chaitanya/files/bigText")

     val words = bigFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).count()

     println(words)
  }
}
```

After looking in to your project explorer you need to right click scala folder and select build path -> use as source folder.

Comment: how did you run? I tried your code in Intellij Idea working fine for me.

Comment: i run in scala IDE

Comment: right click on file name and run as Scala Application??

Comment: yeah.same right click-->Run as-->Run Configurations --> scala Apllication..

Comment: Aren't you trying to run WordCount class ?  But your screen-shot says you are running Sample.

Comment: can you show the package where the WordCount class is ?

Comment: i added package explore screenshot.can you click package explore link in my question..thanks

Comment: right click scala folder and select build path -> use as source folder.

Comment: give a try with maven compile. Auto file compile having issue with recent version of scala eclipse IDE. i had the same issue.surviving with maven for sometime.